# convert image 75 dpi to 300 dpi using Imagemagick PHP

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert, jpeg2000

I'm attempting to increase a very low resolution jp2 image to a higher DPI so that the image can been seen without any inconvenience to our eyes.

I have been successful in reading a jpeg2000 encoded string and displaying it as a PNG file. (Below is  the code)

```
$imagedata = "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";

$image=base64_decode($imagedata);

// Create Imagick object
$im = new Imagick();

// Convert image into Imagick
$im->readImageBlob($image);

//Set the output format
$im->setImageFormat("png");

header('Content-type: image/png');

echo $im;
```

I read it is a possibility to increase the DPI using ImageMagick. See here http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18241

How do I achieve this in my PHP script (NOT through command line) ? Any help and guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Increase the DPI (which is a mere metadata that can be patched) or increase the size in pixels?

Comment: Changing the dpi of an image doesn't improve it, it is just a number in the header. If your image is 2 pixels by 2 pixels, you have 4 pixels. If you print the image at 1 dpi it will be 2 inches by 2 inches, if you print it at 100 dpi, it will be 1/50 of an inch square, but either way it will still only have four blocks/blobs of colour.

Comment: Okay, The Image that I get is 160x200 pixels at 72DPI and ain't clear (sort of smudged) when seen with naked eyes. I would like to improve that and bring to a better quality (say something like what we have in passport)..

Comment: Please show the image.

Comment: There are programs that are supposed to do what you want; from memory it started off years ago with "Genuine Fractals". There are a few programs that are based on it but it is not available in Imagemagick.

Comment: You could also do some unsharp filtering, which is actually a sharpening filter.

Comment: Here's the image.. https://drive.google.com/open?id=18zOABH0_5hXRDAyn58Fs5AOVZX8dli2H I'm ok with the present size as is.. but would love to have better picture clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [UK Government website for the Passport Office](https://www.gov.uk/photos-for-passports/rules-for-digital-photos), it says that passport photos need to be at least 600px wide by 750px tall.

Let's start with a photo of adequate quality (if not content) for Mr Bean at 600x750:

[image]

If we now resize him down to the same as your image (160x200), then back up you will see the quality has suffered through trying to represent the image at 160x200 and you can't invent all those pixels you lost - they are gone for good. Look at his teeth and the highlights in his eyes:

```
convert bean.jpg -resize 160x200 -resize 600x750 result.jpg
```

[image]

So, all you can do in Imagick is:

```
Imagick::resizeImage ( int $columns , int $rows , int $filter , float $blur [, bool $bestfit = FALSE [, bool $legacy = FALSE ]] )
```

to go back up to 600x750 and experiment with setting the filter to `Catrom` or `Lanczos`. But you can't invent stuff that isn't there...

Comment: Hey Mark, Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated.